# How to redirect all files in a directory with the filename in the query string?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have set up a new store system on a web site. The old one uses static HTML files, while the new one uses JS combined with a JSON file that has all the information in it for the store. I am going to make a page that will take the filename, and convert it to the new URL format. For example, https://example.com/store/products/tremendous.html is now https://example.com/store/store.html?pageType=item&page=store-tremendous (or whatever the ID is, replacing store-tremendous). How would I use the .htaccess file to redirect /store/products/tremendous.html to /redirect.html?page=tremendous.html, and so on, for all the files in the products directory?

**EDIT:** I figured it out, it's really simple. See my comment. I'll mark as resolved once I am able to.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it's actually really simple. Here's the relevant part of my .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /store/products/ /redirect?page=
Redirect 301 /store/accessories/ /redirect?page=
```

This will redirect any page in either of those folders to my redirect script, while appending the filename to the end of the URL.